# Displaying image from device in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

[image]Let's say I have an image under `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1542035689920.jpg` path. Is it possible to display this image in `<image>` tag just by assigning `.url` property? Probably not, if so are there any good solutions to do it? I'm trying to do a thumbnail of an image in the list, the way I've done it is to read an image as base64, convert it with the usage of canvas then display it. Problem is it takes too much time to render all the images.

```ts
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.defectImages.forEach(defectImage => this.loadThumbnail(defectImage.url))
  }

  loadThumbnail(url) {
    return this.fileProvider.getDefectCachedImage(url)
      .then(data => {
        return this.generateFromImage(data, 400, 400, 0.5, thumbnail => {
          let image = document.getElementById(url) as any;
          image.src = thumbnail;
        })
      });
  }

  showImage(url: string) {
    this.photoViewer.show(this.fileProvider.getCacheFolderPath() + url, '', {share: true})
  }

  generateFromImage(img, MAX_WIDTH: number = 700, MAX_HEIGHT: number = 700, quality: number = 0.5, callback) {
    var canvas: any = document.createElement("canvas");
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = () => {
      var width = image.width;
      var height = image.height;

      if (width > height) {
        if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
          height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
          width = MAX_WIDTH;
        }
      } else {
        if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
          width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
          height = MAX_HEIGHT;
        }
      }
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

      // IMPORTANT: 'jpeg' NOT 'jpg'
      var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);

      callback(dataUrl)
    };
    image.src = img;
  }
```

It is working but working too slow. I have noticed PhotoLibrary package but as far I know it access to the shared memory and my pictures are being held in app only space.

Comment: If you set the `src` of the image tag to the file on the device, what are you seeing?  You should be able to do just a standard image tag with source (no base64 needed).  There are some livereload and wkwebview considerations though.

Comment: then all I am seeing is just malformed image tag

Comment: just notice im getting : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/io.

Comment: Are you running either on iOS or with `--livereload`?

Comment: got it, it was due to bug in webview plugin, after i downgraded it seems to work OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue with the latest webview. The latest webview is not allowing the local resources to load. It was working fine on Ionic 2. Though not an optimal solution, I'm pasting the solution that worked for me.

```
ionic cordova plugins rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
cordova clean android
```

And you can build(ionic cordova build android) the app and test it.